# sum groups rows of numpy matrix using list of lists of indices

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

slice numpy array using lists of indices and apply function, is it possible to vectorize (or nonvectorized way to do this)? vectorized would be ideal for large matrices

```
import numpy as np
index = [[1,3], [2,4,5]]
a = np.array(
       [[ 3,  4,  6,  3],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [1, 1,    4,  5]])
```

summing by the groups of row indices in `index`, giving:

```
np.array([[8, 10, 12, 14],
          [17, 19, 24, 37]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's an almost* vectorized approach -

```
def sumrowsby_index(a, index):
    index_arr = np.concatenate(index)
    lens = np.array([len(i) for i in index])
    cut_idx = np.concatenate(([0], lens[:-1].cumsum() ))
    return np.add.reduceat(a[index_arr], cut_idx)
```

*Almost because of the step that computes `lens` with a loop-comprehension, but since we are simply getting the lengths and no computation is involved there, that step won't sway the timings in any big way.

Sample run -

```
In [716]: a
Out[716]: 
array([[ 3,  4,  6,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 1,  1,  4,  5]])

In [717]: index
Out[717]: [[1, 3], [2, 4, 5]]

In [718]: sumrowsby_index(a, index)
Out[718]: 
array([[ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [17, 19, 24, 27]])
```

**Approach #2 :** We could leverage fast matrix-multiplication with [`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to perform those sum-reductions, giving us another method as listed below -

```
def sumrowsby_index_v2(a, index):
    lens = np.array([len(i) for i in index])
    id_ar = np.zeros((len(lens), a.shape[0]))
    c = np.concatenate(index)
    r = np.repeat(np.arange(len(index)), lens)    
    id_ar[r,c] = 1
    return id_ar.dot(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using a `list comprehension`...

For each `index list` in `index`, create a new list which is a `list` of the `rows` in `a` of those `indexes`. From here, we have a `list` of `numpy` `arrays` which we can apply the `sum()` method to. On a `numpy` `array`, `sum()` will return a new `array` of each `element` from the `arrays` added which will give you what you want:

```
np.array([sum([a[r] for r in i]) for i in index])
```

giving:

```
array([[ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [17, 19, 24, 27]])
```